# FireStore Security Rules for Content Owner only and Public

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have Security rules like below in my Firestore database
just to be sure I want to ask here for best practice of security rules firestore

So I have collection of userData and communityPost

user data only can be access by content owner that create it (content owner can create and update it)

for community post I want everyone auth and non-auth user can read the data (public)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /userdata/{document} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
    
    match /communityPost/{document} {
     allow read: if true;
   }
  }
}
```

is this correct rules ?? this is my first time dealing with collection based rules,
thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the properties within the document

```js
    match /userdata/{document} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner
    }
```

or you can match the document id to the user
You can check the properties within the document, notice the match path

```js
    match /userdata/{userID} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userID
    }
```

As for making it public, Firestore discourages purely open database so you need a few conditional statements
You can check the properties within the document

```js
    match /communityPost/{document} {
     allow read: if resource.data.public == true;
   }
```

Comment: how I can set the property of document to public ??

Comment: You only need a value in the document as public == true - for example: `.set({public: true})` 
fields are nullable - so you don't need the field for a `public == false` situation